# Does this system have a root?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, systems-of-equations

I have a set of nonlinear equations to solve which came up in my research.

I take the conditional expected value of $N$ functions (which are $log()$) of $N$ independent **non-identically** distributed exponential random variables $X_1,..,X_i,..,X_j,...X_N$. These random variables are all known by their mean values.

Then I obtain the set of functions $ f_1(\cdot),..,f_i(\cdot),..., f_N(\cdot)$, where the $i^{th}$ function $f_i(\cdot)$ is as follows:

$$f_i(d_1,...,d_N)=[P(A_i)\cdot E_{X \mid A_i}\log(1+\cfrac{d_i}{\sum_{j \neq i}  X_j})] -c_i$$

The summation $\sum_{j \neq i}  X_j$ is the sum of all the $N-1$ random variables except $X_i$ i.e., sum over all $j=\{1,...,N\}\smallsetminus\{i\}$

The probability of the event $A_i$ is given by $P(A_i)=\prod_{j\neq i} P(X_j>d_j, X_j=\max\{X_j,Y_j,Z_j\})$. Here too the product is over all $j=\{1,...,N\}\smallsetminus\{i\}$

For a given $j={1,...,N}$ the three random variables $X_j, Y_j, Z_j$ are i.i.d., i.e., the $N$ sets $\{X_j, Y_j, Z_j\}$ for $j=1,...N$ are individually i.i.d. The $c_i$ for $i=1,...N$ are positive constants.

Then I have $N$ functions of the $N$ unknowns $d_i$ for $i={i,..., N}$.

Then I want to find a root of this set of functions such that $f_i=0$ for all $i$.

Is there a method to solve it or is there some criteria that would assure the existence of a solution?

I have tried Banach's fixed point theorem. But find it difficult to find a metric so that this set of functions has a contraction.

Thank you.

Comment: What are your resulting equations? Also, I would assume that you mean "root" instead of "toot" and "or" instead of "of".

Comment: If the functions $f_i$ are not made explicit, the question seems so general as to be empty.

Comment: Hello Did. I included more information about the set of functions. Thanks

Comment: Hello Did and Marty. Do you have any suggestions for me please?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have: use @ (I saw your comment by chance).

Comment: @Did May I know what type of theory I should look for to solve this please?

Comment: What your equations are is not clear to me yet. Assuming this point is settled, what are the parameters of the system and what are the unknowns?

Comment: @Did Thank you. I rewrote the problem. There are no parameters. I only have a set of unknowns $d_1,...,d_N$. The expected value of $log()$ of equation $i$ is conditional on the event $A_i$. Then I multiply by the probability of event $A_i$ and then subtract a positive constant to obtain $f_i$

Comment: Nearer from a math question but not there yet: what is the event $A_i$? how come the probability of the event $[X_j=\max\{Y_j,Z_j\}]$ is not zero since $X_j$, $Y_j$ and $Z_j$ are independent and continuous? and there is no information on the parameter of the exponential distribution of $X_j$?

Comment: @Did Thank you. I have corrected the $max\{X_i,Y_i,Z_i\}$. The exponential random variables are all known as there mean values are assumed to be known. Only unknowns are the $d_i...,d_N$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the setting is the following. One considers some positive real numbers $c_i$ and some independent random variables $X_i$, $Y_i$, $Z_i$, all exponential, where the common parameter of $X_i$, $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ is some positive $\lambda_i$. Let $\lambda=(\lambda_i)_i$ and $S=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N$. For every $x=(x_i)_i$ with positive entries, and every $i$, let $\hat x_i=(x_j)_{j\ne i}$ and 
$$
A_i(\hat x_i)=[\forall j\ne i, X_j\geqslant\max\{Y_j,Z_j,x_j\}].
$$
The question is to find some  $x=(x_i)_i$ with positive entries such that $f_i(\lambda,x)=c_i$ for every $1\leqslant i\leqslant N$, where
$$
f_i(\lambda,x)=E\left[\log\left(1+\frac{x_i}{S-X_i}\right);A_i(\hat x_i)\right].
$$
To solve this system explicitely seems hopeless in the general case. To show that some solution exists (or not), one could study the functions $f_i(\lambda,\ )$ on the boundary of their domain. And maybe study in depth the case $N=2$...

Comment: Thank you. Do you think the function $f_i(x_1,...x_N)$ will form a contraction in non-negative real $N$ space?